# Groovy testing groovy.sql.Sql - MockSql

Tags: sql, unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking

Need some help of mocking sql.eachRow().

I have a service which I'd like to test which is as follows:

```
class MyService {
def dataSource

def method1(id) {
    def map = [:]
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    def queryString = 'select col1, col2 from tbl_1 where id = ?
    sql.eachRow(queryString, [1]) { row ->
        map.put(row.val1, row.val2)
    }
    return map
}
```

}

I'm trying to test this with MockFor

Code:

```
class MyServiceTest extends Specification {
@Test
def "test method1"() {
    setup:
    def row = [:]
    row["col1"] = "1"
    row["col2"] = "val1"
    def mockResult = [row]

    Sql.metaClass.constructor = {dataSource -> return new MockSql("") }
    def mockSql = new MockFor(Sql.class)
    mockSql.demand.newInstance { def datasource ->
        return mockSql
    }
    mockSql.demand.eachRow { def arg1, def arg2, closure ->
        // run the closure over the mock array
        mockResult.each(closure)
    }

    when:
    def result = service.method1(1)

    then:
    result == ["1":"val1"]
}
```

}

Getting the below error with earRow argument types

```
No signature of method: com.kenexa.assess.MockSql.eachRow() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList, xyz_closure103) values: [select col1, col2 from tbl_1 where id = ?]
Possible solutions: eachRow(java.lang.Object, groovy.lang.Closure)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.kenexa.assess.MockSql.eachRow() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList, xyz_closure103) values: [select col1, col2 from tbl_1 where id = ?]
Possible solutions: eachRow(java.lang.Object, groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Comment: There are a few things about the code which are going to be problematic.  One thing that would help is seeing what is in your `MockSql` class.

Comment: One issue is that you are setting up a `.demand` for the `Sql` class, but the `Sql` class is not what your service is interacting with.  You have mocked the `Sql` constructor to return a `MockSql` (there is probably no good reason to do that, but that is what the code is doing) so when the service invokes `eachRow ...`, it is doing that on an instance of `MockSql`, not an instance of `Sql`.